# Apple Mach-O Linker Error : Linker Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have gone through other similar questions but am still not able to solve my problem.

I am trying to build a codebase but I am getting this error every time I try to build in XCode.

[image] I tried to see all the libraries and frameworks used but could not find any extra library being used.
My library list :

[image]

I also went through the paths defined but there I couldn't find anything which I am missing that would led to this error.

[image]

I know the error is happening because I am missing something but what am I possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: Are  you building for simulator? Try to clean and build for iOS device.

Comment: @pkc456 Yes, I was building for the simulator.